# looping over all files in the same directory in R

Tags: r

the following code in `R` for all the files. actually I made a for loop for that but when I run it it will be applied only on one file not all of them. BTW, my files do not have header.

Comment: let out the `[[i]]`

Comment: then how to loop over files?

Comment: you use the iterator `i` to read a new file every iteration. Thus you *loop over files*, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

You use `[[` to subset something from `peaks`. However, after reading it using the file name, it is a data frame with then no more reference to the file name. Thus, you just have to get rid of the `[[i]]`.

```
for (i in filelist.coverages) {
  peaks <- read.delim(i, sep='', header=F)
  PeakSizes <- c(PeakSizes, peaks$V3 - peaks$V2)
}
```

By using the iterator `i` within `read.delim()` which holds a new file name each time, every time R goes through the loop, `peaks` will have the content of a new file.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `i` is referencing to a name file. Use indices instead.

And, by the way, don't use `setwd`, use `full.names = TRUE` option in `list.files`. And preallocate `PeakSizes` like this: `PeakSizes <- numeric(length(filelist.coverages))`.

So do:

```
filelist.coverages <- list.files('K:/prostate_cancer_porto/H3K27me3_ChIPseq/', 
                                 pattern = 'island.bed', full.names = TRUE)

##all 97 bed files
PeakSizes <- numeric(length(filelist.coverages))
for (i in seq_along(filelist.coverages)) {
  peaks <- read.delim(filelist.coverages[i], sep = '', header = FALSE)
  PeakSizes[i] <- peaks$V3 - peaks$V2
}
```

Or you could simply use `sapply` or `purrr::map_dbl`:

```
sapply(filelist.coverages, function(file) {
  peaks <- read.delim(file, sep = '', header = FALSE)
  peaks$V3 - peaks$V2
})
```